# An explanation for the change in the value of `this` in the following snippet of code?

Tags: javascript, this

```
function wrap(func) {
  console.log('0', this)
  return function x() {
    console.log('1', this)
    func()
    return function z() {
      console.log('3', this)
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  x: 5,
  test: wrap(function y() {
    console.log('2', this)
  })
}

obj.test()()
```

The code above logs

```
// 0 Window
// 1 Object
// 2 Window
// 3 Window
```

I'm having trouble understanding what dictates what the value of `this` should be.

`// 0 Window` makes sense because this is when wrap is first called, and at this point its value `this` should not be set to `obj`

`// 1 Object` makes sense `obj.test` is now equal to `function x()`, which properly logs `this` as `obj`

`// 2 Window` I'm not sure why this happens. Why does the value of `this` not propagate to `func()`? I thought `this` was supposed to refer to the owner of the function. Does this mean that even though `function y()` was created inside obj it was somehow hoisted to the window?

`// 3 Window` Likewise with `function z()` why was the value of `this` not passed down from `function x()`. Isn't the value of `this` supposed to propagate there?

Comment: I believe since `func` is passed to the `wrap` function it will get the same `this` value as the `this` inside the `wrap` function.

Comment: As for function `z` it is executed inside the global scope so it makes sense that its `this` value is `window`.

Comment: Yehuda Katz wrote a pretty good blog post about this topic: http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Comment: _"Does this mean that even though function y() was created inside obj"_ `y` was not invoked within `obj`

Comment: @guest271314 so to clarify where a function is invoked determines the value of `this`? And why was it not invoked within `obj` if `console.log('1', this)` was?

Comment: The confusion you seem to be having is that `this` is not like a variable, it is not preserved in a new scope. It is determined in each new scope by a set of rules (others have posted). The reason `1` has `this == obj` is because the function is called directly from the object. In every other case, `this` has a new scope, and it is not being called directly by an object, therefore the context defaults to `window`

Comment: @Damon this is the best explanation I've seen so far. I had a muddled understanding of it before, but you really cleared it up.

Comment: @AR7 `return function x() {
    console.log('1', this)` is invoked at `obj.test()();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following, the *mostly accurate* guidance of [this](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) article, in order, the function calls desugar to

- `wrap.call(window, function() {})`
- `obj.test.call(obj)`
- `y.call(window)`
- `z.call(window)`

The thing to keep in mind is that `this` does **not** propagate through function declarations. The value of `this` depends entirely upon how the function called.

The reason I was confused was because I had gotten a bit too used to arrow functions, which preserve the value of `this` for you.

```
function wrap(func) {
  return () => {
    console.log(this)
    return () => {
      console.log(this)
      func()
      return () => console.log(this)
    }
  } 
}
```

this desugars to

```
function wrap(func) {
  var _this = this;

  return function () {
    console.log(_this);
    return function () {
      console.log(_this);
      func()
      return function () {
        return console.log(_this);
      };
    };
  };
}
```

and shows that you have to explicitly pass down the value of `this`. Though even with arrow functions, it's important to note the call to `func` will not preserve the value of `this`. I would need to do `func.call(this)` in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The 'this' binding is very confusing. However, if you remember these following rules, it will be easier to understand. According to Javascript documents, there are four rules for 'this' binds in these orders:

1. new operator
2. explicit or hard binding via call or apply methods
3. implicit binding with containing object, like a method of an object
4. default (global)

From your scripts, only rules #3 and #4 apply because there are no new operators and call or apply methods.

So the explanations are:

// 0 Window  - rule #4 default (global)

// 1 Object  - rule #3 implicit binding with containing object, like a     method of an object, obj.test in your case

// 2 Window  - rule #4 default (global)

// 3 Window  - rule #4 default (global)